# Twitter SDK for IPad, weired error on twitter login

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, twitter-oauth

when I try to share on twitter I do the following steps

```
if (!twitterEngine)
{
    twitterEngine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
    twitterEngine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    twitterEngine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: twitterEngine delegate: self];

    if (controller) 
        [currentController presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    else
        [self postTwitterStatus];
}
else {
    [self postTwitterStatus];
}
```

after I got the twitter login view and after I put my pass and user and click add app

I get crash on asembly code, which I don't have an error message, but I saw something weiered also that in the delegates

```
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {
    NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
    [self postTwitterStatus];
}
```

I got that authintication succeeded but I get that the username == null

how can I solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did NOT get THIS error, but a similar one using Twitter+OAuth by Ben Gottlieb. If you are using this thing, it is required to use https and not http to connect to twitter.
go to: `SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m` and change to:

```
- (SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *) initOAuthWithDelegate: (NSObject *) delegate {
    if (self = (id) [super initWithDelegate: delegate]) {
        //CHANGED FROM 'HTTP' TO 'HTTPS':
        self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
        self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

give it a try, i'm not sure it's the same as your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Every thing looks fine to me. check with this [example](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) and see weather you are getting username in this.